# Cannot mark question as answered on the Geographic Information Systems (GIS) Stack Exchange site

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I want to mark a question as answered on the "[Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)" Stack Exchange site.

I marked the answer as accepted, and the green tick mark appeared:

[image]

However, when I am coming back to this page, the tick mark is not green, so it looks like I have not accepted the answer.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Because you accepted your another answer**

You are referring to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/241819/104114) to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/241814/104114) in the screenshots on the question.

But you already accepted [another answer of your's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/252710/104114).

So once you accept another answer, the previously accepted answer become unaccepted.

> A question can have only one accepted answer

Comment: So,I cannot accepted more then one?

Comment: no. as said in answer, a question can have only one accepted answer